# matching 9 digit string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match a 9 digit numeric string with the following code but it only returns this `<` Looking at the source code of the remote page here is an example of what I am trying to match `&cd=225730313"`

```
$url = file_get_contents($source);
preg_match('/([0-9]{9})/', $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the second parameter to preg_match. You ay also consider fetching the parenthesis (index 1) instead of the whole pattern (index 0).

```
$url = file_get_contents($source);
preg_match('/([0-9]{9})/', $url, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

I think the reason you get `<` is because you have used $match previously and it contains a string beginning with `<`. preg_match as used in your question will not change $match, and therefore $match[0] is the first character of the string contained in $match (strings can be accessed like arrays in PHP).

Comment: @Emil Vikström Ah!! it works but gets the first 9 numbers it comes across. is there a way to get the numbers that come after `&cd=` like in this here `&cd=264230303"

Comment: Just change the pattern: /&cd=([0-9]{9})/

Comment: @Emil Vikström i tried that and it returns nothing. i also did var_dump($match) and it returns an empty array

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source of the page you're checking? Maybe they use &amp; instead of & or something like that.

Comment: @Emil Vikström hate to bother you again if there are 2 sets of digits on the same page how would i get both at the same time? instead of copying and pasting the same code 2 times

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{9}+$/', $match)
```

or maybe this :

```
preg_match('/\d{9}/', $match)
```

Comment: @SpyrosP no luck :( still returns `<`

Comment: hmm, should work. what about the second one ? For the first, you can remove ^ and +$, they seem to not apply in your case.

Comment: Why the plus sign? Your first regex will return a number whose length is a multiple of 9 (18, 27, 36, ...) (if your call to preg_match was correct, which it isn't)

Comment: yes, and it would then also call a cab. What are you talking about ? {9} means 9.times, not multiples of 9. It's not a lambda function, it's a simple regular expression.

Comment: Your plus sign will match multiples as well.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct. But what's purpose of your plus sign then?

Comment: It's actually not relevant, i just pasted from one of my projects and did not notice it was there. That's why i then mention that he can lose it. Yet, in this occasion, it's like a redundant token that does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = file_get_contents($source);
preg_match('/([0-9]{9})/', $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Index `0` contains the match against the whole pattern, `1` the first subpattern and so on.

Edit:

To get the digits after `&cd=` I would suggest to expand the pattern, that it matches this too.

```
/&cd=([0-9]{9})/
```

Comment: thank you it works but gets the first 9 numbers it comes across. is there a way to get the numbers that come after `&cd=` like in this here `&cd=264230303"

Comment: do you know how i can add a loop to check for multiple instances of this match and return them if there is more than one on a page